# Use HFP and SPP with HC-05

Tags: android, bluetooth, spp

Is it possible to use the HC-05 Bluetooth Module as Handsfree Device with an Android Device?

At the moment we use the HC-05 in SPP Mode to transfer data, but we also want to handle incoming calls and start calling. And maybe other handsfree stuff.

We use the standard UUID "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB". We know how to change the CoD of the HC-05 but how to change the UUID?

With the standard UUID the phone is not responing on Handsfree initiation command "AT+BRSF=20\r"

Do we need to change the UUID by flashing the BC417 or is there another possibility?

Comment: Hi any updates on this question?